# function getting executed at the start of for loop instead of after it

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to execute some code after a for loop in nodejs file

```
let DirectoriesDHRD = getDirectories('.\\captures\\ref');
for (let i = 0; i < DirectoriesDHRD.length; i++) {
//some things I coded
 if (i==DirectoriesDHRD.length-1)
{
//execute this
}
```

I've already seen a similar issue and one of the solution was to do that conditional statement, but it didn't work for me. I've tried to debug the issue and I noticed that the loop iterator I get to its limit value (`DirectoriesDHRD.length-1`), then it executes the code inside the conditional statement before executing the other code outside of it.

It s like this is what happening:

```
for (let i = 0; i < DirectoriesDHRD.length; i++) 
{
    // conditional statement code
}

for (let i = 0; i < DirectoriesDHRD.length; i++) 
{
    // other code
}
```

How can I fix this ?

**EDIT:** here's the code I've been working on

```
for (let i = 0; i < DirectoriesDHRD.length; i++) {
    let DirectoriesSCENARIO= getDirectories('.\\captures\\ref\\'+DirectoriesDHRD[i]);
    for (let j=0;j<DirectoriesSCENARIO.length;j++){
        let dirtestresult = path.join('VisualTests',DirectoriesDHRD[i],DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        let dirref = path.join('captures','ref',DirectoriesDHRD[i],DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        let dirtest= path.join('captures','test',DirectoriesDHRD[i],DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirtestresult)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirtestresult,{ recursive: true });
        }
        fs.readdir(dirref, function (err, files) {
            let TestResult="";
            if (err) {
                console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            else if (files.length == 0) {
                console.log("test skipped or pending");
                TestResult="skipped/pending";
            }
            else {
                TestResult="passed";
                files.forEach(function (file,Status) {

                    var filepathref=path.join(dirref, file);
                    var filepathtest=path.join(dirtest,file);
                    if (fs.existsSync(filepathtest))
                    {
                        Status=compare(file,filepathref,filepathtest,dirtestresult);
                        if (Status=="failed"){
                            TestResult="failed";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("test missing screenshots");
                        TestResult="failed";
                    }
                });
    
            }
            switch (TestResult) {
                case 'passed':
                  pass++;
                  break;
                case 'skipped/pending':
                  skip++;
                  break;  
                case 'failed':
                  fail++;
                  break;
                default:
                  console.log(`error`);
            }
            let Test={
                name : DirectoriesSCENARIO[j],
                tag : DirectoriesDHRD[i],
                status : TestResult
            }; 
            
            let TestJson=JSON.stringify(Test, null, "\t");
            alltests.push(Test);
            console.log(alltests[i]);
            fs.writeFile(dirtestresult+"\\test.json", TestJson, (err) => {
                if (err)
                  console.log(err);
                else {
                  console.log("File written successfully\n");
                }
              });
    
       
        });
    }
   if (i==DirectoriesDHRD.length-1)
   {
    let result=JSON.stringify({pass: pass,fail: fail, skip :skip},null,"\t");
    fs.writeFile(".\\VisualTests\\result.json", result, (err) => {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else {
          console.log("Result File written successfully\n");
        }
      });
    let jsonresult=JSON.stringify(alltests,null,"\t");
    console.log("///////////////////////");
    console.log(jsonresult);
    fs.writeFile(".\\VisualTests\\Tests_results.json",jsonresult,(err)=>{
        if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log("Result File written successfully\n");
      }
    }); 

   } 
    
}
```

getdirectories:

```
function getDirectories(path) {
    return fs.readdirSync(path).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(path + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    });
}
```

compare:

```
function compare(file,filepathref,filepathtest,dirtestresult){
    var Status="passed";
    var imageref = PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync(filepathref));
    var imagetest=PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync(filepathtest));
    var i=file.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
    var {width, height} = imageref;
    var diff = new PNG({ width, height });
    var result=pixelmatch(imageref.data, imagetest.data, diff.data, width, height, { threshold: 0.4 ,alpha:1});
    fs.writeFileSync(dirtestresult+"\\"+i+".png", PNG.sync.write(diff));
    var percent=(result*100)/(width*height);
        console.log(percent);
        if (percent>15)
        {
            Status="failed";
        }
    return Status ;    
}
```

Comment: What does `getDirectories` look like? This is likely some asynchronism.

Comment: @code If the array isn't being filled in because of asynchrony, the loop would end immediately and never execute the `if` code at all.

Comment: Make sure you have `i==DirectoriesDHRD.length-1` and not `i=DirectoriesDHRD.length-1`

Comment: Please show us ALL the real code involved here.  It seems likely that there are asynchronous operations involved (that you are not showing) and we need to see those in order to help and advise on an appropriate solution.  Please don't shorten or change the code for posting in your question.  Please show all the relevant REAL code.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry I just didn't thought the rest of the code would be relevant in this matter.I'll be more cautious next time

Comment: You have a mix of synchronous and asynchronous calls from the `fs` library (generally wrong to mix them).  The asynchronous ones are causing you problems because you haven't written them correctly.  First question.  Is this code part of a server?  Or just a stand-alone, single user script?  This determines whether you should be using only asynchronous calls or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 it 's a utility stand-alone nodejs script I use to compare between 2  images and generate a comparison file with pixelmatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a mix of some synchronous calls from the `fs` module and some asynchronous and the asynchronous ones were not waiting for your loops so things were going out of sequence.

Since this is a utility stand-alone script (not a server), you can just use the synchronous version of things everywhere and simplify your coding flow.  Change `fs.readdir()` to `fs.readdirSync()` and `fs.writeFile()` to `fs.writeFileSync()`.

Also, be sure to declare any variable before using it.

```
for (let i = 0; i < DirectoriesDHRD.length; i++) {
    let DirectoriesSCENARIO = getDirectories('.\\captures\\ref\\' + DirectoriesDHRD[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < DirectoriesSCENARIO.length; j++) {
        let dirtestresult = path.join('VisualTests', DirectoriesDHRD[i], DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        let dirref = path.join('captures', 'ref', DirectoriesDHRD[i], DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        let dirtest = path.join('captures', 'test', DirectoriesDHRD[i], DirectoriesSCENARIO[j]);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirtestresult)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirtestresult, { recursive: true });
        }
        let files = fs.readdirSync(dirref);
        let TestResult = "";
        let Status;
        if (files.length == 0) {
            console.log("test skipped or pending");
            TestResult = "skipped/pending";
        } else {
            TestResult = "passed";
            files.forEach(function(file, Status) {

                var filepathref = path.join(dirref, file);
                var filepathtest = path.join(dirtest, file);
                if (fs.existsSync(filepathtest)) {
                    Status = compare(file, filepathref, filepathtest, dirtestresult);
                    if (Status == "failed") {
                        TestResult = "failed";
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("test missing screenshots");
                    TestResult = "failed";
                }
            });

        }
        switch (TestResult) {
            case 'passed':
                pass++;
                break;
            case 'skipped/pending':
                skip++;
                break;
            case 'failed':
                fail++;
                break;
            default:
                console.log(`error`);
        }
        let Test = {
            name: DirectoriesSCENARIO[j],
            tag: DirectoriesDHRD[i],
            status: TestResult
        };

        let TestJson = JSON.stringify(Test, null, "\t");
        alltests.push(Test);
        console.log(alltests[i]);
        fs.writeFileSync(dirtestresult + "\\test.json", TestJson);
        console.log("File written successfully\n");
    }
    if (i == DirectoriesDHRD.length - 1) {
        let result = JSON.stringify({ pass: pass, fail: fail, skip: skip }, null, "\t");
        fs.writeFileSync(".\\VisualTests\\result.json", result);
        console.log("Result File written successfully\n");
        let jsonresult = JSON.stringify(alltests, null, "\t");
        console.log("///////////////////////");
        console.log(jsonresult);
        fs.writeFileSync(".\\VisualTests\\Tests_results.json", jsonresult);
        console.log("Result File written successfully\n");
    }
}
```

Note that error handling with the `Sync` versions is via throwing an exception so if you want to catch those exceptions in order to continue rather than abort, you will need to put appropriate `try/catch` blocks in whatever scope you're trying to catch the errors.  Right now the code assumes you put a try/catch block at a higher level and catch the error there.

Comment: thank you so much ! it worked perfectly . this is my first time working with nodejs so i didn't really know the difference between sync and async methods.